# Using descriptive statistics as input in SPSS

Tags: spss

I want to perform a repeated measures ANOVA in SPSS using the descriptive statistics. So my input is:

```
Descriptive Statistics          
        Mean    Std. Deviation  N
M1MI    3,8000  1,03280         10
M1MA    5,3000  2,16282         10
M2MI    7,0000  1,88562         10
M2MA    2,2000  1,54919         10
M3MI    6,2000  1,03280         10
M3MA    4,2000  1,75119         10
M4MI    4,7000  ,67495          10
M4MA    4,9000  1,19722         10
```

Does anyone know how I have to adjust my syntax?

My design is as follows:

```
Dependent variables: Progress1, Progress2, Progress3, Progress4 

Within subject factor 2: M (I/A)
```

Comment: You can only perform repeated measures ANOVA if you had data on all ten subjects, so you know the value for each subject for each of your 8 treatments. Since you only know the mean and SD for each treatment groups, repeated measures ANOVA is not possible.

Comment: This question should not be closed. It is not about SPSS really; the requested procedure can't be done in *any* program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Not in SPSS nor any other package. Doing an ANOVA requires the raw data.

However, if you are willing to assume that each variable has a particular distribution that is defined by the mean and sd (e.g. Normal, t with a certain df, etc) and if you are also willing to specify the relationships among the repeated data, then you can use the information you have to create simulated data and then do ANOVA on those data.

I would be very very hesitant to do that. If I did do that, I would be sure to do lots of sensitivity analyses.